# Running Angular app (with router) without a server

Tags: angular, typescript, electron, angular-router

I've made a simple Angular app that uses routing module to display information pages or test page.

When I build the app and run it from local index.html it doesn't work, which is to be expected, since Angular docs say you NEED to serve your app if you use router.

The goal was initially to build the app to work inside Electron, but right now it looks like it's far more complicated then I anticipated.

Is there a way to run Angular app that uses routes from single file? Or, maybe, is there a way to turn this app into an electron app?

Comment: Creating electron app with angular is pretty simple. You might find your answer here. https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/desktop-apps-with-electron-and-angular/

Comment: @ShreenilPatel I tried adding electron to my project and running `ng build` and `electron .` to no avail. Routes seem not to work still, if the app is simply built and then put into electron

Answer (score 0):

even if you convert to electron as per electron definition as i mentioned in last place it run the backend on node js so there is no way you will be able to use router with file type URL as it require run time to load different file and require some run time to do so " Electron (formerly known as Atom Shell) is an open-source framework developed and maintained by GitHub.

Electron allows for the development of desktop GUI applications using front and back end components originally developed for web applications: Node.js runtime for the backend and Chromium for the frontend."